# SQLite Persistence project : errorMsg

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios5

I use errorMsg in my NSAssert, but I only defined it as NULL and never used it to get the actual error message. So, it will always be NULL and there is no point to use it in NSAssert.

<...>

```
char *errorMsg = NULL;


    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update, -1, &stmt, nil)

        == SQLITE_OK) {

        sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, i);

        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [field.text UTF8String], -1, NULL);

    }

    if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE)

        NSAssert(0, @"Error updating table: %s", errorMsg);
```

<...>

will anyone give a solution? 
when I run the app, there is no harm. but then, when I press the home button, the process paused and shows me this:

> 2013-05-20 23:57:50.156 SQLite Persistence[5373:c07] *** Assertion failure in -[LPEViewController applicationWillResignActive:], /Users/Me/Developer/SQLite Persistence/SQLite Persistence/LPEViewController.m:84 2013-05-20 23:57:50.158 SQLite Persistence[5373:c07]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error updating table: (null)' ** First throw call stack: (0x2094012 0x11a1e7e 0x2093e78 0xc37665 0x3c09 0xc624f9 0x20ee0c5 0x2048efa 0xb96bb2 0xe2bb1 0xe2c3d 0xece0c 0xf5e74 0xf6beb 0xe8698 0x1fefdf9 0x1fefad0 0x2009bf5 0x2009962 0x203abb6 0x2039f44 0x2039e1b 0x1fee7e3 0x1fee668 0xe5ffc 0x2b4d 0x2a75) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception (lldb)

Comment: Which line is line 84 from your `LPEViewController.m` file?

Comment: Add an `else` statement to the first `if` statement and log the error in case the prepare statement fails.

Comment: What is the value of `update`? of `i`? of the text field?

Comment: You never set `errorMsg`. You need to call `sqlite3_errmsg` and assign it to `errorMsg`.

Comment: You fell into the assert because you got a bad return code.  The crash is what NSAssert does.  And there are many reasons why the return code from sqlite3_step might be other than SQLITE_DONE, some of them "normal".

Comment: (Basically, you don't know what you're doing.  Either back off and go with something like FMDB or spend at least a day studying the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html).)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues:

1. You never set the `errorMsg`. Make sure to set it to `sqlite3_errmsg` (or just use that function directly).
2. Your custom error message ("Error updating table") is a little misleading, too, as it would imply that you're reporting the name of a table, whereas your choice of variable name suggested you really wanted to report the SQLite error message.
3. If `sqlite3_prepare_v2` fails, you don't report any error message. Furthermore, rather than stopping and reporting an error if `sqlite3_prepare_v2` failed, you proceed to try to call `sqlite3_step`, even though there's no valid statement to perform. The problem with that is that it would undoubtedly replace the meaningful error message you would have received after `sqlite3_prepare_v2` failed with some useless message about executing statements in the wrong order.
4. You don't check the success or failure of your `sqlite3_bind` statements. It would be prudent to do so (though I suspect you're more likely to fail at the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` statement).

Anyway, maybe you want something like:

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update, -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSAssert(0, @"prepare failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

if (sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, i) != SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    NSAssert(0, @"bind 1 failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

if (sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [field.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    NSAssert(0, @"bind 2 failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) {
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    NSAssert(@"step error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

Whether you want to use `NSAssert` or just `NSLog` and immediately return, I'll defer to you, but this code sample will check more SQLite failure conditions and report meaningful errors.

Comment: @arun - For what it's worth, I'd generally suggest people check out [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). It's a thin wrapper, but also greatly simplifies the writing of SQLite code.