# How can I use text and numbers in a single row using SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I'm using Objective-C to add data to my SQLite DB. I have a column with the text attribute.

The problem is, there will be both numbers and letters in that row. When I tried doing that, it gave me an error. But when I took away the number, there wasn't any error, and it worked just fine.

Here's my code:

```
insert into myTable values(null '%@'), myText; // myText = @"2 Phones"
```

My question is, how is it possible to have both numbers and regular text inside a row in SQLite?

**Update**

I'm doing the following:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into myTable values(null, '%@')", self.textView1.text];
```

I will then be doing like so:

```
[self.dbManager executeQuery:query];
```

to make the string an `sqlite` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would generally prepare (with `sqlite3_prepare_v2`) a SQL statement with `?` placeholders for your values:

```
insert into myTable (string_column_name, int_column_name) values (?, ?)
```

You'd then use `sqlite3_bind_text` to bind a string value to the first `?` (using a 1-based index):

```
if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [string UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"bind text error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    return NO;
}
```

And one would use `sqlite3_bind_int` to bind a numeric value to the second `?`:

```
if (sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 2, value) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"bind int error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    return NO;
}
```

You can then call `sqlite3_step` to perform the SQL and `sqlite3_finalize` to release the memory associated with the prepared statement.

Comment: What if I don't know the order of which comes first, the int or text? Also, see my updated question. Can you please edit the code you wrote based on the code I provided? Thanks! :)

Comment: In my opinion, you should always reference the column names in the SQL (like my example), so that the order is unambiguous. It's poor design to make the success of SQL to be contingent upon the order of the fields in the physical implementation of table. If you really had to, you could the `table_info` pragma to retrieve the information about the order of the columns, but that's a lot of work to go through when the problem is solved immediately by specifying the column names in the SQL.

Comment: I'm pretty new to `sqlite`. At your second step, you wrote: "You'd then use..." Do the if statements do them, or do I have do it before the if statements? If it's the latter, then can you please provide an example?

Comment: @Jounson The `if` statements do it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17333157/1271826 for another example. Basically call `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, followed by `sqlite3_bind_xxx` for each of the `?` placeholders in the SQL, `sqlite3_step` to perform the SQL, and `sqlite3_finalize` to free the memory associated with the statement. And you want to check the return code from each of those (and you can generally combine the `sqlite3_xxx` call with the `if` statement).

Comment: @Jounson By the way, if you're new to SQLite, while it's good to learn how the calls work, you might also consider [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), a nice Objective-C wrapper around SQLite. It gets you out of the weeds of this SQLite C API...